# RFC-6238 TOTP implementation not matching examples

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, sha1, totp

Here is my simple implementation of RFC 6238

```
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
namespace totp;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //string secret = "12345678901234567890"; // HOTP
        string secret = "3132333435363738393031323334353637383930"; // TOTP

        while (true)
        {
            long unix = 1111111109;
            long unixRoundedRaw = (long)Math.Floor(unix / 30.0);
            long unixRounded = (long)Math.Floor(unix / 30.0) * 30;
            // unix -= unix % 30;
            Console.WriteLine("unix: " + unix);
            Console.WriteLine("time: " + DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(unix).DateTime);
            Console.WriteLine("tron: " + DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(unixRounded).DateTime);
            Console.WriteLine("totp: " + generateTOTP(secret, unixRoundedRaw, 6));
            Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    static string generateTOTP(string secret, long time, int digits)
    {
        string result = "";
        // while (time.Length < 16) { time = "0" + time; }

        //byte[] msg = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2 }; // HOTP
        byte[] msg = BitConverter.GetBytes(time); // TOTP
        //if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) { Array.Reverse(msg); }

        Console.WriteLine("hext: " + BitConverter.ToString(msg).Replace("-", ""));

        byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret);
        //if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) { Array.Reverse(key); }

        HMACSHA1 hmac_sha = new HMACSHA1(key);
        byte[] hash = hmac_sha.ComputeHash(msg);
        //if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) { Array.Reverse(hash); }

        Console.WriteLine("hash: " + BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", ""));

        int offset = hash[^1] & 0x0f;
        int bin_code = (hash[offset] & 0x7f) << 24
               | (hash[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16
               | (hash[offset + 2] & 0xff) << 8
               | (hash[offset + 3] & 0xff);

        result = (bin_code % Math.Pow(10, digits)).ToString();

        while (result.Length < digits) { result = "0" + result; }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I've left some commented lines out that were used for testing against HOTP (RFC 4226) which work correctly. The outputted digits match the example in the specsheet:

exert from RFC4266:

```
                     Truncated
   Count    Hexadecimal    Decimal        HOTP
   0        4c93cf18       1284755224     755224
   1        41397eea       1094287082     287082
   2         82fef30        137359152     359152
```

My code:

```
hext: 0000000000000002
hash: 0BACB7FA082FEF30782211938BC1C5E70416FF44
totp: 359152
```

However, when running my code to generate a TOTP code, the time matches, and the hex value of T matches, but the TOTP is incorrect.

exert from RFC6238

```
  +-------------+--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
  |  Time (sec) |   UTC Time   | Value of T (hex) |   TOTP   |  Mode  |
  +-------------+--------------+------------------+----------+--------+
  |      59     |  1970-01-01  | 0000000000000001 | 94287082 |  SHA1  |
  |             |   00:00:59   |                  |          |        |
  |  1111111109 |  2005-03-18  | 00000000023523EC | 07081804 |  SHA1  |
  |             |   01:58:29   |                  |          |        |
```

My code:

```
unix: 1111111109
time: 18/03/2005 01:58:29
tron: 18/03/2005 01:58:00
hext: EC23350200000000
hash: 0AE6677BAD3CD817B337F34E37AEC0D12EED7CC4
totp: 962199
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Reversing the value of T (switching to Big endian) does not produce an output that matches the example, which is why I left those lines commented. I am sure that the ASCII encoding of time isn't the issue, as the hex value of T matches the example. I've seen some people suggest that the secret should be encoded in Base32, however this seems to be for matching their implementation with Google Authenticator, and not the actual spec.

Comment: RFC 6238 does contain a reference implementation. This is executable, see online here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/O5Y. Just compare the intermediate results of the reference implementation with those of your implementation to find out where the problem is caused.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Topaco for your suggestion - i ran through every intermediate variable and found my secret was being encoded, instead of taken as a literal array of bytes. Parsing this using this function solved the issue:

```
    static public IEnumerable<byte> GetBytesFromByteString(string s)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < s.Length; index += 2)
        {
            yield return Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(index, 2), 16);
        }
    }
```

I also had to switch the key to Big endian.
My code is now spec compliant for SHA1
Thank you!